# Powershell Login Script

Tags: powershell, scripting, startupscript

I have been struggling to get into the next phrase of testing towards creating a logon script that will map drives if they belong to a Group and removed if they don't. This is on top of a few drives that needs to be mapped by default.

Below is my simple code, but when I tried to test it won't execute the one inside the if condition even though the condition has been met. I have run gpupdate and restart the test computer several times, but to no avail.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$user = $env:USERNAME

#--------- Checking for XCOMP Group ----------
if ((Get-AdGroupMember -Identity "XCOMP" -Recursive | Where-Object { $_.SamAccountName -eq $User }))
{
    $ServerMap = "\\servernetwork\Share Drive"
    $MappVariable = Test-Path $ServerMap
    
    if ($MappVariable) {
        net use M: $ServerMap
    }
}
else
{
    net use M: /delete
}
```

Any chance one has the idea as to why?  or any other code that is more efficient than this?

Thank you so much team!

- Around condition operator or another cmdlet.

Comment: First - do you really have `ActiveDirectory` module installed on all computers? Second - if you have this module installed correctly you don't have to import it explicitly - it will be loaded automatically by PowerShell if needed. Third - if you really want to use the module you'd be better off using `#Requires -Modules ActiveDirectory`. This would prevent the script from running if the necessary module is not available. And Last - why don't you map the drives by GPO directly? There you can use groups to filter as well. ‍♂️

Comment: Yes, I have the modules installed and its running with other commands. The only problem occurs when going through conditions.

Regarding the GPO, I have a few groups which is on the first If() is it something I need to tweak? The expression on that IF statement is to determine if the $user belongs or equal to the XCOMP group.

Comment: Why aren't you doing this with a Group Policy? It's much easier. We had extremely complex drive mappings based on membership in various groups that were done very simply via Group Policy settings. Asking how to do so on [sf] would probably save you tons of time and effort.

Comment: I actually don't know what you mean. I just wanted to point out that you don't need a script at all for what you want to do.  ‍♂️